# UISwipeGestureRecognizer with UIView created in a separate class not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I created a UIView in a separate class, and I am trying to animate it in my ViewController. It is supposed to work like the notification screen on the iPhone that appears when you swipe down, and then you can swipe it back up.

I can get my custom view to swipe down, but when I try to swipe it back up, the swipe up gesture is not being initiated.

I am a novice, so any help is greatly appreciated!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NotificationView *notificationView = [[NotificationView alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:notificationView];



    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDownGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDown:)];
    swipeDownGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUpGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUp:)];
    swipeUpGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownGestureRecognizer];
    [notificationView addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpGestureRecognizer];

}

-(void) swipeUp: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer{

    UIView *notificationView = [[NotificationView alloc]init];
    notificationView = recognizer.view;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        notificationView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 723);
    }];

}

-(void) swipeDown: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) recognizer{

    UIView *notificationView = [[NotificationView alloc]init];
    notificationView = recognizer.view;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        notificationView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 723, 414, 723);
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a property with your notificationView and keep a reference to it, and not create a new one over and over.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NotificationView *notificationView;
```

And in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
       _notificationView = [[NotificationView alloc] init];

// Important line to solve your problems on gestures not fired off on your notification view
_notificationView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [self.view addSubview:_notificationView];
```

and simply change:

```
-(void)swipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        _notificationView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 723, 414, 723);
    }];

}
```

You should look into a tutorial on how properties work.
And you should [look into This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281512/swipe-method-is-getting-called-twice) to avoid animations getting called multiple times etc by handling gesture states.

Answer (score 0):

notificationView in ViewDidLoad should be assigned to the viewControllers property, and you should not alloc init views in the gesture recognizer actions.